# How to correctly check for permission for Push Notifications?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications, service-worker, web-notifications

From what I've observed, `Notification.permission` and `navigator.permissions.query({name:'push', userVisibleOnly:true})`
both can be used to obtain the permission status for sending push notifications (Notification.permission is permission for showing notification while the former is permission for sending push but in practical use cases, they're interchangeable from my understanding), "granted" and "denied" are common but the former gives "default" permission in chrome if the user has neither blocked the permission not granted, while permissions.query shows "prompt".

I wanted to know which one is preferable in which scenario to check  the permissions and when can they give different results in case user has granted or blocked permission. Does it depend on browser or browser versions or whether we're executing the code in service worker scope or normal global scope that which one we use? Also I read that there's some difference between their behaviour on Firefox browser, but I'm not clear on it.